# Edited messages in telegram bot API Java

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm currently working on a telegram bot controller using Java and I want to use the method getEditedMessage() from class Update as the following

```
@Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update)
    {

        System.out.println(update.getEditedMessage());
    }
```

I tried to print the output and it seems to be something like

`Message(messageId=13, messageThreadId=null, from=User(id=1450878765, firstName=hi, isBot=false, lastName=mohamed, userName=null, languageCode=en, canJoinGroups=null, canReadAllGroupMessages=null, supportInlineQueries=null, isPremium=null, addedToAttachmentMenu=null), date=34789327489, chat=Chat(id=32843432432, type=private, title=null, firstName=hi, lastName=bye, userName=null, photo=null, description=null, inviteLink=null, pinnedMessage=null, stickerSetName=null, canSetStickerSet=null, permissions=null, slowModeDelay=null, bio=null, linkedChatId=null, location=null, messageAutoDeleteTime=null, hasPrivateForwards=null, HasProtectedContent=null, joinToSendMessages=null, joinByRequest=null, hasRestrictedVoiceAndVideoMessages=null, isForum=null, activeUsernames=null, emojiStatusCustomEmojiId=null, hasAggressiveAntiSpamEnabled=null, hasHiddenMembers=null), forwardFrom=null, forwardFromChat=null, forwardDate=null, text=/new_post  ***this is test  added some edit text***, entities=[MessageEntity(type=bot_command, offset=0, length=9, url=null, user=null, language=null, customEmojiId=null, text=/new_post)], captionEntities=null, audio=null, document=null, photo=null, sticker=null, video=null, contact=null, location=null, venue=null, animation=null, pinnedMessage=null, newChatMembers=[], leftChatMember=null, newChatTitle=null, newChatPhoto=null, deleteChatPhoto=null, groupchatCreated=null, replyToMessage=null, voice=null, caption=null, superGroupCreated=null, channelChatCreated=null, migrateToChatId=null, migrateFromChatId=null, editDate=463294732894, game=null, forwardFromMessageId=null, invoice=null, successfulPayment=null, videoNote=null, authorSignature=null, forwardSignature=null, mediaGroupId=null, connectedWebsite=null, passportData=null, forwardSenderName=null, poll=null, replyMarkup=null, dice=null, viaBot=null, senderChat=null, proximityAlertTriggered=null, messageAutoDeleteTimerChanged=null, isAutomaticForward=null, hasProtectedContent=null, webAppData=null, videoChatStarted=null, videoChatEnded=null, videoChatParticipantsInvited=null, videoChatScheduled=null, isTopicMessage=null, forumTopicCreated=null, forumTopicClosed=null, forumTopicReopened=null, forumTopicEdited=null, generalForumTopicHidden=null, generalForumTopicUnhidden=null, writeAccessAllowed=null, hasMediaSpoiler=null, userShared=null, chatShared=null)` .

It seems from that response that it contains only the edited message and doesn't contain the original message

The original message in the bot is
`/new_post  this is test`

The message after editing is
`/new_post  this is test  added some edit text`

Is there any way to get also the original message as I need it to make some comparisons later ?

I tried to read the method documentation and I didn't get an answer.